# How do i build cassandra-pdo (cassandra pdo driver)?

Tags: pdo, cassandra

I have studied the document http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/source/browse/README.md. When I build config.m4 I get this error:

```
./config.m4: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `pdo-cassandra,'
./config.m4: line 1: `PHP_ARG_WITH(pdo-cassandra,     whether to enable PDO cassandra support,'
```

Why?  Should I use another parser to read config.m4?

Answer (score 2):

These steps work for me on Ubuntu:

1. `apt-get install libboost-all-dev php5-dev libpcre3-dev pkg-config libthrift-dev`
2. `phpize`
3. `./configure`
4. `make`
5. `make install`

I'll get the docs updated to include these steps.  Hopefully we can put together some binary packages some time soon.

Comment: thank you Tyler Hobbs. your method is right as PDO document says.I use CentOS 
but get some error when make.

/phpcassa-0.8.a.2/cassandra-pdo/cassandra_driver.cpp:691: error: invalid conversion from 'const zend_function_entry*' to '_zend_function_entry*'

Comment: @Cheng I had a similar issue on 5.2. I posted the patch that worked for me:
https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/issues/detail?id=7